# Catching ECONNREFUSED in node.js with http.request?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to catch ECONNREFUSED errors when using a HTTP client in node.js. I'm making requests like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = { host: 'localhost', port: '3301', path: '/', method: 'GET' };

http.request(options).on('response', function (res) {
  // do some stuff
});
```

I can't figure out how to catch this error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:614:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:605:18)
```

If I do `request.on('error', function () {});`, it doesn't catch it. If I do it like this:

```
var req = request.on(etc)
req.on('error', function blah () {});
```

Then I get `TypeError: Object false has no method 'on'`.

Do I really have to do a top-level uncaught error thing to deal with this? At the moment whatever I do my whole process quits out.

Edit: I found some blog posts on how to do it by creating a `connection` object, calling `request` on that, and then binding to errors on the `connection` object, but doesn't that make the entire `http.request()` shortcut useless?

Comment: I figured this out. It's because I was doing this:


var req = http.request(options).on('response', function (res) {
  // do some stuff
}).end();

req.on('error', handleError);
I was calling on the req.on after calling end(). Facepalm!

Comment: For future views, would you be able to post a link to that blog post? I think that would be very helpful to have here.

Answer (score 26):

Any reason you're not using http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.5/api/http.html#http.request as your base? Try this:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  // Bind 'data', 'end' events here
});

req.on('error', function(error) {
  // Error handling here
});

req.end();
```

Comment: it does not work<pre>var req = http.request("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
  // Bind 'data', 'end' events here
});

req.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error)
  // Error handling here
});

req.end();</pre>

Comment: Have you tried with a valid options object instead of passing a url as the first parameter?

Comment: Using node 10 and I can confirm this solution does work handling the the ECONNREFUSE error.

Comment: Also note that 'req' is not the same as 'res'. I'm handling on error event for both to make sure my app does not crashes.

Answer (score 7):

Each call to `http.request()` returns its self.
So try it like this...

```
http.request(options.function(){}).on('error',function(){}).end();
```

Comment: Simple solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've got a solution for this, having tried all the suggestions on this (and many other) pages.

My client needs to detect a turnkey product that runs embedded windows. The client is served from a different machine to the turnkey.

The turnkey can be in 3 states:

1. turned off
2. booted into windows, but not running the turnkey app
3. running the turnkey app

My client sends a 'find the turnkey product' GET message to my nodejs/express service, which then tries to find the turnkey product via http.request.  The behavior for each of the 3 use cases are;

1. timeout
2. ECONNREFUSED - because the windows embedded phase of the turnkey is
   refusing connections.
3. normal response to request (happy day scenario)

The code below handles all 3 scenarios. The trick to catching the ECONNREFUSED event was learning that its handler binds to the socket event.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var url = require('url');


function find (req, res) {
    var queryObj = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

    var options = {
        host: queryObj.ip, // client attaches ip address of turnkey to url.
        port: 1234,
        path: '/some/path',
    }; // http get options

    var badNews = function (e) {
        console.log (e.name + ' error: ', e.message);
        res.send({'ok': false, 'msg': e.message});
    }; // sends failure messages to log and client  

    // instantiate http request object and fire it
    var msg = http.request(options, function (response) {
        var body = '';

        response.on ('data', function(d) {
            body += d;
        }); // accumulate response chunks  

        response.on ('end', function () {
            res.send({'ok': true, 'msg': body});
            console.log('sent ok');
        }); // done receiving, send reply to client

        response.on('error', function (e) {
            badNews(e);
        }); // uh oh, send bad news to client   
    });

    msg.on('socket', function(socket) { 
        socket.setTimeout(2000, function () {   // set short timeout so discovery fails fast
            var e = new Error ('Timeout connecting to ' + queryObj.ip));
            e.name = 'Timeout';
            badNews(e);
            msg.abort();    // kill socket
        });
        socket.on('error', function (err) { // this catches ECONNREFUSED events
            badNews(err);
            msg.abort();    // kill socket
        });
    }); // handle connection events and errors

    msg.on('error', function (e) {  // happens when we abort
        console.log(e);
    });

    msg.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those not using DNS (you can also use `request` instead of `get` by simply replacing `get` with `request` like so: `http.request({ ... })`):

```
http.get({ 
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 443,
    path: '/books?author=spongebob',
    auth: 'user:p@ssword#'
 }, resp => {
    let data;

    resp.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', () => console.log(data));
}).on('error', err => console.log(err));
```